# Adding old T1s to a new configuration

Tags: networking, t1

As embarrassing as it is, my facility is running on two T1 lines. One connects us to AT&T and the other connects us directly to our corporate facility. This is a mirror of an old system we once had. The old T1s used for the old system are still sitting in our server room, and are inactive.

It makes sense to me, that we should be able to use those old T1s to increase the speed of our connection to our corporate office by simply redirecting them, by contacting AT&T.

The head of networking tells me this impossible. However, 1.5Mbit from our corporate office is crippling.

My question is:

Is it possible to redirect old T1 connection to be usable in a new network configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: `The old T1s used for the old system are still sitting in our server room, and are inactive.`  So... your question is... what, *precisely*?  The available bandwidth on an inactive T1 is exactly 0Kbps, BTW.

Comment: Bonded T1 is definitely a thing. Whether or not you can actually implement it is another question. The corporate T1 is most likely a PVC (permanent virtual circuit), while the ATT T1 is not. You would need to speak to ATT as well as the party that provides the corporate T1 to see if it's possible to bond both T1 circuits.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I am trying to figure out if it is feasible to use the old T1s on our current network to increase our bandwidth to our corporate office. And, I understand that if it is inactive, it adds nothing to bandwidth.

Comment: @joeqwerty Sorry if it was confusing, but I believe both connections are provided by AT&T. I will see if I can give them a call about the migration/implementation. Thanks for the solid input.

Comment: @user229808 That still doesn't really clarify what you're asking.  You can bond/aggregate T1s into a single link for more capacity, yes.  What do your old, inactive T1s have to do with anything, though?

Comment: @HopelessN00b I want to make them ACTIVE to, as you say, aggregate them. This is my first job in IT. I am trying to learn as I hit the ground with my face here. The head of Networking told me that is would be impossible to add them to our current connection to increase our bandwidth increase. I came here for a second opinion.

Comment: @user229808 Well, at the very least, you're approaching this problem wrong.  If you want more bandwidth, you need to talk to your ISP, and not try to... scavenge old cables from your server room, or whatever it is you have in mind for those inactive connections. So, you would ask AT&T for a quote to add another T1 (or two) into an aggregated link.  Except, why would you want to do that?  Unless there's no other option, you don't want to be using T1's, so you should be asking AT&T if you can get a fiber link or a metro Ethernet connection or the like to your office.

Comment: You should also ask ATT what the CIR (committed information rate) for the current T1 is. The CIR is the bandwidth that they guarantee to be available to you at all times. If they're not meeting the CIR then you probably have some recourse in your SLA to get them to resolve it. (You do have an SLA for the T1, correct?)